# How to get a socket id and a list of connections from OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl

I'm working with OpenSSL and I'm trying to figure out how to view the ID's of current socket connections:

My code that listens for connections:

```
while(1)
{
   struct sockaddr_in adds;
   unit len = sizeof(addr);

   int client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len);
   if(client > 0)
   {
     std::cout<<"Client incoming";
   }
     ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
     SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

     if(SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0)
     {
        std::cout<<"Handshake error";
     }
     else
     {
        //Do Stuff with connection
   }

   SSL_free(ssl);
   close(client);
}
```

How can I get a socket id and a list of connections from openssl?

Additionally 'int client' is also being set to '4', despite the documentation stating it should either be 1, 0 or <0?

Comment: `int client` is being set with return value of `accept`. Which documentation mentions `accept` return value should be etiher 1,0 or < 0?

Comment: @Prabhu https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_accept.html

Comment: but `client` is being assigned from `accept` and not `SSL_accept`.

Comment: OpenSSL doesn't have a list of client connections. If you want one, maintain it yourself. Mostly, you don't.